# Trying to order my list by date time but fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Trying to order by date but always when I create the colum 'date', and add date NOT NULL to it, it will echo '0000-00-00' instead of the date.

And then I did some SQL changes

after reading articles

```
CREATE TABLE `driptone`.`announces` (
`announcements`       text,
`updated_at`          TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_at`          DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (created_at)
);
```

but now when I submit it says

MySQL problem:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What did I do wrong?

```
//error_reporting(0);
$announcements = $_POST['announcement'];    
if (!empty($announcements)) {
    if (strlen($announcements) > 10) {
        $date = date("Y/m/d");
        $sql="INSERT INTO announcements (message, date_time) VALUES ('$announcements,$date')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql))
        die('MySQL problem:'.mysql_error());
    } else {
    echo 'Need to be atleast 10 characters long';
    }
} else {
echo 'Fields are empty';
}
$queryPerson = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announces ORDER BY created_at DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryPerson) ) {
 echo $row['announcements'] . ' ' . $row['created_at'] . '<br /><br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO announcements (message, date_time) VALUES ('$announcements,$date')";
```

You have to separate the values with quotes, you can't put them in one quote

```
VALUES ('$announcements','$date')";
```

Also you have the table name and column name incorrect in your code.

---

Also take the primary key of of the created_at filed.

Comment: Now I get MySQL problem:Duplicate entry '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

The `'$announcements,$date'` should be `'$announcements','$date'`.

Though, use prepared statements from [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's because `VALUES ('$announcements,$date')` is considered as one string.

Rewrite it as: `VALUES ('$announcements', '$date')`.

Also I would recommend to switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) as the mysql driver is very outdated.
Your code is very unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are going to sort by the created_at date, you need an index on that column.

Second you are getting that error, because you are trying to insert into columns named `message` and `date_time` when your table structure has these fields named `announcements` and `created_at`.  You need to use the right column names.

Third, you need to put single quotes around each of the values you are trying to insert, not the whole group of values.